# Libraries for crosscompiler

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, visualgdb

I build project for `Raspberry Pi` with help of `VisualGDB` , Visual c++ and `GCC 8.3.0 GDB 8.2.1 Revision 3 Raspbian Buster` crosscompiler that comes with it. It runs fine, but how to deal in cases when I need link to libraries? Should I build all required libs with my current crosscompiler? For example how to deal with `libxml2` library?

Comment: If on windows host, I would run a raspberry pi as a virtual machine and do your work there.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I build all required libs with my current crosscompiler?

You either build them, or you find some RaspberryPi Raspbian Buster package for them.

If your RaspberryPi is connected to the internet, consider using some `apt` command and find some [`*.deb` package](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/pkg-basics.en.html) for Raspbian.

### you need Linux skills

PS. My opinion is that installing [Debian](https://debian.org/) or [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) on your PC (e.g. on a separate hard disk, in dual boot: Linux for programming, Windows for games) is easier: you will **learn first how to deal with a Linux OS thru the command line**. Once you got these skills, deaing with a Raspbian is easier. Read of course [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), then the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) and at last see [Linux From Scratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/).

Comment: I can install libs with apt on my Pi. But I will need  these libs locate on windows machine that process build since I use Windows crosscompiler.

Comment: Did you consider installing Debian on your PC, in dual boot with Windows? If not, why? Of course, backup your important data (to a remote site, or some USB disk) before trying. As I am explaining, you need to acquire Linux skills. This takes weeks at least, and could take [ten years](http://www.norvig.com/21-days.html)

Comment: I do build on Windows and run on Pi. I like Visual Studio editor and VisualGDB helps me with that.